# How to use andWhere and orWhere in Doctrine?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

```
WHERE a = 1 AND (b = 1 Or b = 2) AND (c = 1 OR c = 2)
```

How can i make this in Doctrine?

```
$q->where("a = 1");
$q->andWhere("b = 1")
$q->orWhere("b = 2")
$q->andWhere("c = 1")
$q->orWhere("d = 2")
```

this isnt correctly... Should be:

```
$q->where("a = 1");
$q->andWhere("b = 1")
   $q->orWhere("b = 2")
$q->andWhere("c = 1")
   $q->orWhere("d = 2")
```

but how can i make it? In Propel is function **getNewCriterion**, and in Doctrine...?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
$q->where("a = 1")
  ->andWhere("b = 1 OR b = 2")
  ->andWhere("c = 2 OR c = 2")
  ;
```

Comment: Then why not just put it all in the `where()` call?

Comment: I wouldn't be satisfied with this kind of syntax... What if you try to migrate to some sick kind of "SQL" where `OR` will be replaced by `||`... How does this work, when you need to use `b = ? OR b = ?`

Comment: @Dems Yes, it is certainly possible. This method is faster, tho.

Comment: @Vyktor: doctrine handles that. This is actually DQL, not SQL - Doctrine QL that is transformed to valid vendor-specific SQL transparent to you. Also: `andWhere("b=? OR b=?", array(1, 2))`.

Comment: I think this should be 

    $q->where("a = 1")
      ->andWhere("(b = 1 OR b = 2)")
      ->andWhere("(c = 2 OR c = 2)");

Comment: It works but personally I don't consider this the correct approach. One of the main points of using a builder is to let the code describe your logic, not your strings (even if doctrine takes care of translating to the right language as Maerlyn said). Another main point of using a builder is to be able to compose your query without concatenating strings (for example what if you have a list of matches like [status = 'inProgress' OR status='done' OR status='whatever' etc.]). You want to be able to loop through a list when needed. I think Serge answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: Serge's answer to use the Expression builder is a more satisfying way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 113):

Here's an example for those who have more complicated conditions and using Doctrine 2.* with [`QueryBuilder`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods):

```
$qb->where('o.foo = 1')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
      $qb->expr()->eq('o.bar', 1),
      $qb->expr()->eq('o.bar', 2)
   ))
  ;
```

Those are expressions mentioned in Czechnology answer.

Answer (score 27):

One thing missing here: if you have a varying number of elements that you want to put together to something like

```
WHERE [...] AND (field LIKE '%abc%' OR field LIKE '%def%')
```

and dont want to assemble a DQL-String yourself, you can use the `orX` mentioned above like this:

```
$patterns = ['abc', 'def'];
$orStatements = $qb->expr()->orX();
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    $orStatements->add(
        $qb->expr()->like('field', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $pattern . '%'))
    );
}
$qb->andWhere($orStatements);
```

Comment: Is this solution safe? What about SQL injection?

Comment: Not sure tbh, this is creating DQL, not SQL, but it might be possible. @paul-attuck pointed out something similar. If you want to stay save, i guess it would be something like
`$qb->expr()->like('field', $qb->expr()->literal('%:val_i%'))` and then `$qb->setParameter('val_<i>', $value)` but its likely that you screw up the like-statement with this and dont get what you want.

Comment: This solution is not safe, is 100% venerable to SQL Injection attack

Answer (score 14):

Why not just

```
$q->where("a = 1");
$q->andWhere("b = 1 OR b = 2");
$q->andWhere("c = 1 OR d = 2");
```

**EDIT**: You can also use the [Expr class](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) (Doctrine2).

Comment: The question is for doctrine 1.2, the docs you linked is for 2.0.

Comment: @Maerlyn, well, the question doesn't have the `doctrine-1.2` tag, so I can't be sure which one the user means - in that case I implicitly expect the most current one.

Comment: My mistake, didn't know there was andWhere and orWhere in doctrine2's query builder.