# Doctrine - DQL- multiple ORs nested within one encapsulating AND

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I can't find an example of DQL, here's what the semi-pseudocode would look like:

```
Bring back invoices
- Where company id = 5
AND
    (
      ->where('DATE(i.startPeriod) BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
      ->orWhere('DATE(i.endPeriod) BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
      ->orWhere(':startDate BETWEEN DATE(i.startPeriod) and DATE(i.endPeriod)')
      ->orWhere(':endDate BETWEEN DATE(i.startPeriod) and DATE(i.endPeriod)')
    )
```

So you have four OR's nested within one encapsulating AND.

Does anyone know how to do that with Doctrine DQL?  Nest a bunch of OR's within one giant AND?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use andWhere and orWhere in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095113/how-to-use-andwhere-and-orwhere-in-doctrine)

Comment: I don't know if you would want to use only one "Where" condition with parentesis to nest other conditions
     
->where(company id = 5 AND ('DATE(i.startPeriod) BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate' OR 'DATE(i.endPeriod) BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate' OR . . . .) )

Comment: it's called an Exclusive Or.  I did it in doctrine a while ago I would have to look it you have to use the `$expr` thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use the `Expr()` class with the query builder.

```
// $qb instanceof QueryBuilder

$qb->select('i')
   ->from('invoices', 'i')
   ->where('c.id = :cid')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
       $qb->expr()->between('i.startPeriod',':startdate',':enddate'),
       $qb->expr()->between('i.endPeriod',':startdate',':enddate'),
...
```

You can read more about the `Expr()` class in [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class).

**EDIT:**

Just realized your initial question asked specifically about DQL. You can use parens in DQL to group things, so something like this.

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
   'SELECT i FROM Invoices i 
    WHERE c.id = :id 
    AND (
        (i.startPeriod BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) 
        OR 
        (i.endPeriod BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)
        OR 
        (:startDate BETWEEN i.startPeriod AND i.endPeriod)
        OR
        (:endDate BETWEEN i.startPeriod AND i.endPeriod)
    ) JOIN i.company c');
```

Comment: It's still cool to see another way of doing it like that though, cool thanks.

Comment: I prefer the query builder personally, because it makes it easier to build a query programmatically instead of having to build a string. That's why my brain went there first.

Comment: That is true. Agreed.