# How to combine andWhere and orWhere with Doctrines Criteria

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, criteria

I want to create a rather complex and flexible query with Doctrines `Criteria`. I have an `andWhere` that is included in every query, but then (depending on input) I want to add some optinal parameters with `orWhere`.

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();

/* Add Criteria for last 55 Days (every query) */
$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->gte('gameCreation', $long));

/* Gather optional Params */
$orxList = array();

/* Optional Criteria */
if (!empty($champions)) {
    foreach ($champions as $c) {
        $orxList[] = Criteria::expr()->eq('champion',$c);
    }
}

...
$criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->orX($orxList));
```

This leads to an Exception:

> No expression given to CompositeExpression.

How would I combine such a Criteria with the initial `where` clause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use andWhere and orWhere in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095113/how-to-use-andwhere-and-orwhere-in-doctrine)

Comment: I found that was well, but if the `orWhere` is optional and the query needs to be "extended" I need to create a string query like  `$sql .= 'OR champion = ?`. This doesn't seem right?

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem and solved it like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Expr\CompositeExpression;
...

/* Gather optional Params */
$orxList = array();

/* Optional Criteria */
if (!empty($champions)) {
    foreach ($champions as $c) {
        $orxList[] = Criteria::expr()->eq('champion', $c);
    }
}

...
$criteria->andWhere(new CompositeExpression(CompositeExpression::TYPE_OR, $orxList));
```

As you see the constructor of `CompositeExpression` accepts an array of expressions and this generates the correct query.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `orX()` from Expr class for this, example:

```
$orX = $exp->orX();
$index = 0;

foreach ($champions as $c) {
    $paramName = ':param_' . $index;
    $orX->add($qb->expr()->eq('u.column', $paramName));
    $qb->setParameter($paramName, $c);

    $index++;
}
```

However, if your array are just plain strings/object compared in the same way, consider using WHERE IN [] expression.

Comment: this looks promising, but I can't seem to find the right `Expr()` class?

Comment: Oh, what I meant was the one returned from querybuilder, something like $queryBuilder->expr()->orX().

If you are not using querybuilder I think you can create instance of this class: https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.html



For some reason it's not available in Criteria::expr().

Comment: @PrimuS, use one of these in terms of namespaces:
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Andx;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Orx;