# Doctrine - return results with defined type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

In my db I have data that I've defined by field "type" like:

```
const TYPE_ONE = 'one';
const TYPE_TYPE = 'two';
```

I want to return all results where I have defined value of "type" filed by this two constants and not all of them. ( like (NULL) type).

It seems OR operator is not supported.

My code:

```
return $this->getMyEntityRepository()->findBy([
            'type' => MyEntity::TYPE_ONE || MyEntity::TYPE_TWO
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`OR` operator is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095113/how-to-use-andwhere-and-orwhere-in-doctrine/9095221), but in doctrine you should create a method in your repository for this kind of queries.

Repository:

```
class MyEntityRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function findByType()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->andWhere('r.type IN (:types)')
            ->setParameter('types', [MyEntity::TYPE_ONE, MyEntity::TYPE_TWO])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
return $this->getMyEntityRepository()->findByType();
```

Also you can specify parameter for types to look for.