# Add a where condition to a joined table using NeoTable and Doctrine in PHP

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using NeoTable and Doctrine for database interactions with php,
I need to add one where condition for a joined table, below is the controller code.

```
TutorTable::create($this->userRecord, $this->translator, $this->ismobile)
    ->base('student')
    ->parentTable('Student')
    ->childTable('Tutor')
    ->recordTemplateName('record')
    ->parentField('studentID')
    ->childField('tutorID')
    ->noAutoSuffix()
    ->m('ctrac')
    ->relateTable("StdIins")
    ->customRecordTemplate()
    ->getRecords($this->view);

$debug ? neolog("post tutor") : false
```

There are two models , Student and instructor, one student can have many Tutors and vise versa,
**StdIins** is the intermediate table that stores the relations between student and instructors, it contains columns StudentID, tutorID, centerID. I want to add a where condition in above code so that it fetches records for a specific centerID, Does anyone have any idea?

I tried putting a where condition directly for Studenttoins but it resulted in doctrine exception.

Comment: You can also write `$debug && neolog("post tutor");`. No need to return false when not needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use andWhere and orWhere in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095113/how-to-use-andwhere-and-orwhere-in-doctrine)

Comment: Let me check that